# Should we salt informations that are unique and random

Tags: security, hash, salt

Salt is used when storing passwords in databases in order to protect against dictionary attacks and rainbow tables.

However, let's assume we need to store **unique and random** (sensitive) information about users. Is there still an advantage in salting this information before hashing it ?

Wouldn't salt use, in this case, just add randomness to an already random data (unlike man-typed passwords) ?

Comment: what do you mean by unique and random ? Salt is just placed to prevent decryption. That's all it is. If you must protect that unique and random information, use salt. If you don't, then leave it be.

Comment: Could you elaborate the `unique and random`?

Comment: @Kianii hash don't encrypt, they hash. What the dictionary attack and rainbow is actually tries to find pre-image or secondary image the hash function which are hard to invert.

Comment: @kelalaka What about deterministic encryption ?

Comment: random : no pattern can be identified, unique: for every r1 in the database, there exist no r2 such that r1 = r2

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how **confidential** your information is and what are the consequences when this data is compromised. Is it a [**PII**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_information) information like SSN or DOB?

You mentioned that your data is **random** and **unique**. Which means it is difficult to **identify** a **pattern**. If the pattern is random enough then Salting your data may not be required. if you go with salting, then you will have an added responsibility of protecting those salts as well.

I would recommend to use low privileged account, hardening of server, authentication, authorization to protect your data and minimize the surface of attack.

Again, you should come to the conclusion after classification of your data based on [**CIA**](https://www.cmu.edu/iso/governance/guidelines/data-classification.html) principles.

Comment: If the size of the random and unique data is small then easy to find. The bitcoin miners reached ~2^90 hash in year.

Comment: Agree with your comment, This was my generic response without knowing the specifics of data from the post. Based on data classification(High, Med, Low) and then we should come to decision wether to salt it or not. Otherwise, we can use other measures to protect the data.

Comment: "then you will have an added responsibility of protecting those salts as well" What do you mean by this? A salt, but definition, is not sensitive information. If you have to protect the salt, then it's not a salt, it's a pepper and the handling of peppers is very different than the handling of salts (and also much weaker than salts).

Answer (score 1):

This depends very heavily on the size of the search space. For example, we could pretend that social security numbers are both random and unique (they're not actually either, but for the purpose of this discussion we will pretend they are). If you're hashing SSNs, not only do you need a salt, but a salt isn't sufficient. Why? Because there are fewer than 10 billion SSNs in existence. Creating a rainbow table for those is trivial. Even with a salt, it isn't that hard to brute force, even if the values are unique and random.

So to protect a random and unique value that lives in a small search space we have to use a stretching algorithm like PBKDF2, not just a hash. The point of a stretching algorithm is to make computing the hash very slow.

Stretching algorithms always include a salt. But it doesn't have to be a random salt. It could be deterministic (some database identifier + the user id for example, "com.example.mygreatapp:alice"). But for a small search space, you still need it to be unique per user because there are so few items in the search space.

On the other hand, if your random and unique data represents a large search space (not less than 2^64, and ideally at least 2^80), and that search space is sparse (you only use a very small fraction of legal elements), then salting and stretching is likely not required.